# Improve performance of non clustered index creation

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2017, non-clustered-index

I have 2 servers with the same compute power.

I have a table with same structure and almost same number of rows (2 billion), but I'm facing drastic difference in non-clustered index creation time.

Non-clustered index is created on date and datetime columns.

Let me know any other information required to understand problem statement

Comment: You need to provide an execution plan to investigate a performance issue.

Comment: We also need to see the table and index definitions. Don't try describing it, give us `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX`

Comment: Are the SQL Server versions, editions, and patch levels the same? Any concurrent activity? Is the infrastructure (CPUs, memory, storage) identical and SQL memory config the same?

Comment: Creating indexes is hardly CPU bound - do the servers have the same type of disk infrastructure and IOPS provisioning levels?